# ICommandSource's Command throws "The property "Command" does not have an accessible setter" exception in VS 2015

Tags: c#, xaml, 64-bit, visual-studio-2015, design-time

I am currently running the "14.0.23103.0 D14REL" of Visual Studio 2015 and noticed a strange design time exception regarding my custom UI controls which implement the **ICommandSource** interface. What is even more interesting is the fact that the issue is only present if the **targeted platform** is **x64**. When setting the Command property of a custom control which comes from the  implementation of the above interface an "**The property "Command" does not have an accessible setter**" exception is thrown by the VS designer.

Is this a known issue of Visual Studio 2015 when the platform is x64 or am I missing something. Here is some code of my implementation.

- The View

  ```
  <Grid>
      <local:MyControl MySecondCommand="{Binding MyCommand}"
                           Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
  </Grid>
  ```
- The custom Control

  ```
  public class MyControl : Control, ICommandSource
  {
      public static readonly DependencyProperty MySecondCommandProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("MySecondCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

      public ICommand MySecondCommand
      {
          get { return (ICommand)this.GetValue(MySecondCommandProperty); }
          set { this.SetValue(MySecondCommandProperty, value); }
      }

      public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

      public ICommand Command
      {
          get { return (ICommand)this.GetValue(CommandProperty); }
          set { this.SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
      }

      public object CommandParameter
      {
          get
          {
              throw new NotImplementedException();
          }
      }

      public IInputElement CommandTarget
      {
          get
          {
              throw new NotImplementedException();
          }
      }
  }
  ```